# List View displaying Roles and Application User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, user-roles

I am very new to MVC5 and am trying to display a List view of user details and the name of the role they are in. I have set up the roles using MVC Identity.

Below is my ViewModel

```
 public class UserRoleViewModel
{

    public string UserRoleVMId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public bool AccountEnabled { get; set; }


}
```

And my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = (from d in db.Users
                     select new UserRoleViewModel()
                     {
                         UserRoleVMId = d.Id,
                         Title = d.Title,
                         FirstName = d.FirstName,
                         Surname = d.Surname,
                         Email = d.Email,
                         AccountEnabled = d.AccountEnabled,
                         Role = d.Role.Name
                     }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

I am unsure of how to display the role name and am getting the error message

```
does not contain the definition for Role and no extension method Role
```

at

```
Role = d.Role.Name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You have to join Role table with User table to get role name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GetRoles` method :

```
 viewModel.RolesForThisUser = UserManager.GetRoles(userId).ToList();
```

This is useful when you want to display the details of one user.

You should use The property Roles, since a user could have multiple roles:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
       using(var context = new IdentityDbContext()){

    viewModel =
        context.Users
        .Include("Roles")
        .Select(u =>
            new UserRoleViewModel { 
                UserRoleVMId = u.Id, 
                Title = u.Title,
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                Surname = u.Surname,
                Email = u.Email,
                AccountEnabled = u.AccountEnabled,
                Role = u.Roles.First().Role.ToString() 
            }
        ).ToList();
     }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I would not recommend  this! .. he just need to use a join.

Comment: @ Seabizkit, can you explain please why you don't ?

Comment: he is in a loop.... doing it this way,  would be extremely expensive... when he could just do a join on the code he has... which technically is the more correct way anyway.....

Comment: @Seabizkit, That's true, I Updated my answer

Comment: hey really sorry to be a pain, again this is not correct, as this will be doing multiple calls... or inner selects within the main select.... you should use linqpad to see the SQL this generates, but this is better than the first answer... as this is 1 request where as the other was multiple. Again the reason this is not perfect is it has inner selects when they are not needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: this should be better :), isn'it ?

Comment: i know what include does  but when used like that, technically i don't know what it does, i know your intention.... Personally i would do a normal linq left join.... I think  this would still turn out to be some funky SQL..but can not say for sure.

Comment: Iclude  doe's a left join :) to retrieve complex properties

Comment: i know what it does!, if that was directed at me, its is not the same as a normal left join. it is an eager load... which can be seen as a left join but is not the same... but the way it is being consumed in that query would lead to weird SQL.... please insect the actual SQL from that and see that a normal linq left join would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
return view(db.Users.ToList());
```

and in your view on top use

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProjectName.Models.Users>
```

and use this foreach for show content

```
@foreach(var item in Model){<p>@item.Title</p> and etc }
```

Comment: Also would not recommend this... he just need to use a join.